# How can you limit the number of images / videos that can be uploaded to a WordPress post

Tags: uploads

there will be lot of users on my site who will be author uploading their posts. right now, they can upload as many images / videos per post as they want. i want to restrict them to upload maximum 4 images / videos per post. can anybody help me please ?

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'limit_wp_handle_upload_prefilter');
function yoursite_wp_handle_upload_prefilter($file) {
  // This bit is for the flash uploader
  if ($file['type']=='application/octet-stream' && isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
    $file_size = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    if (isset($file_size['error']) && $file_size['error']!=0) {
      $file['error'] = "Unexpected Error: {$file_size['error']}";
      return $file;
    } else {
      $file['type'] = $file_size['mime'];
    }
  }
  if ($post_id = (isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : false)) {
    if (count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}"))>3)
      $file['error'] = "Sorry, you cannot upload more than four (4) image.";
  }
  return $file;
}
```

after you paste this in your theme's functions.php the upload limit should be 4 files total per post.

Comment: +1 and maybe you could attach the error to 'admin_notices'. :)

Comment: @Bainternet - do you have any additional information or remarks on why you need to have that code for the flash uploader?

Comment: @kaiser: i build also an solution for this, like the code on top; but I don't find an hook for admin notices in media upload, inside the iframe. Only an message on upload array is possible.

Comment: @bueltge Ah, ok. Maybe custom js with default admin UI styles will be enough.

Comment: its not fine for maintenance :( i have used current an hook for the information, which mime type and how many objects is possible. see: https://github.com/bueltge/Limit-Upload

Comment: Not working for me. I cannot upload anything....

Answer (score 2):

I have also on solution, use same idea and hooks, only more complex with more functionalities and structured in classes for easy reused. Was an customer project and now its free: https://github.com/bueltge/Limit-Upload

Comment: Firstly, your Adminimize plugin is amazing, secondly, is this available in the Wordpress plugin directory?

Comment: Yes, the Adminimize plugin is also available on the [wp Repo](wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize/). The plugin Limit Upload is only on Github. The problem is the work with free plugin, to much for to give good support.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone wishing to use this code, be sure to include the `'posts_per_page' => -1` if you want to limit the number to more than 5 because the `get_posts` query on this page will only get a max of 5 because of the default paging.

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134500/why-does-get-posts-return-only-5-matching-posts-when-it-should-return-9 for more information. Cheers!

Comment: Actually this would make the number _un_ limited, not a limit greater than 5.