# Allow a specific user role I have created to only upload one image to his media library

Tags: images, media, count, limit, library

Hello guys I was following this article but the code doesn't seem to do anything. The last one by Maruti Mohanty is doing something , it doesn't allow any files to upload with an error. [Set a maximum upload count for users on a specific user role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119964/set-a-maximum-upload-count-for-users-on-a-specific-user-role?newreg=e5d888b445d04742a729b08a915c1142)

As the title says, I would like to allow a specific user role I have created to only upload one image to his media library.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks

John

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a maximum upload count for users on a specific user role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119964/set-a-maximum-upload-count-for-users-on-a-specific-user-role)

Comment: I tried to paste all the codes but It doesn't do anything... I mean I can still upload more than 10 images [for the example] , the last code actual did something but only to restrict all uploading so I couldn't upload any image.

Comment: each code by its own of course modified it to my user role name in this case its ''Artist'' role with subscribers capabilities plus upload_file and delete_post .